# Efficiently detecting rectangular regions (maps) corresponding to a given point

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

We have a (w times h) canvas (width w and height h), which is used as a drawing area. We can define 'maps' or regions in the drawing area, on which the user can click to perform some pre-defined tasks. Each region is defined by a bounding rectangle. An image-map is activated when the user clicks inside it. Two regions may have overlapping rectangles. Whenever the user clicks on a point the canvas, we are required to find the find the image-map(s) to which the point belongs and start the execution of the corresponding task. We can always use a linear list to find the image-maps. But is there a better way, a data structure that could be used to store the image maps so that we can figure out efficiently (in less than O(n) time) which image-maps are activated on user click?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes - use any type of 2D spatial index. The most common is the [quad-tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree), which has O(log(n)) lookup complexity and is also quite quick to build. Implementations are available in all major languages; it is extensively used for all types of mapping applications.

Comment: hey thanks. I was thinking of a similar approach of bi-partitioning the area to left and right halves, but it was not quite working out, or I was not formulating it well.

Comment: no problem. Also, if you store the centers of the rectangles in the quad-tree, the closest centers will also (generally) be the closest rectangles (with a slight variation due to rectangles not being round; you can test this case-by-case).

Answer (score 0):

You may create some sort of optimization to make this work less time in average, but efficient will be still **O(n)** , because there are possibility that users click will execute all **N** possible tasks.

Comment: however, that would require all rectangles to overlap; in that case, the answer itself is O(N). Better algorithms for the more common cases (which would still be O(N) for this scenario) exist.